# Degrading project from 25 API to 23API

Tags: java, android

I made a project for presentation on SDK Api 25 , but now I wanna degrade to API 23 in order to install it on Android 6.0. I tried to reduce versions of libraries in build.gradle, but the project doesn't compile and gives me the error

> The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.3) is too low for project ':app'.
>   Minimum required is 25.0.0
>   How can I degrade the project for Android 6.0

[Screenshot of build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fB6kU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your Android studio version doesn't support this version of Build Tools. It suggests you to update it in the lower part of your screen. Click that link there.